# TKINTER keep on getting the error "pyimage4 not found", the image is the right file format, it works when only the problem function is on another file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a witcher themed combat game for school, and wanted to incorporate an exit confirmation screen.
To do this, I made a button that calls a function called exit_confirmation.
I decided to add a background image to this function, however it will give the error "pyimage4 not found", if I try to change the image to something that I have used before, it will just say "pyimage{number here} not found".

**CLARIFICATION:** the problem function is exit_confirmation()

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

#defining the images
background = PhotoImage(file = 'background.png')
win_screen_image = PhotoImage(file = 'win_screen.png')
lose_screen_image = PhotoImage(file = 'lose_screen.png')
exit_confirmation_image = PhotoImage(file = 'exit_confirmation.gif')

def quit_game():
    exit.destroy
    root.destroy

#work in progress
def exit_confirmation():
    global exit
    exit = Tk()
    confirmtation_canvas = Canvas(exit, height = 202, width = 360)
    confirmtation_canvas.pack()
    confirmtation_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = exit_confirmation_image, anchor = 'nw')
    exit.mainloop()

#function to call the intro canvas
def introduction_canvas():
    #creates the canvas
    c = Canvas(root, height = 720, width = 1280)
    c.pack()

    #places the background image
    c.create_image(0, 0, image = background, anchor = 'nw')
    
    #creates the introduction text
    intro_text = c.create_text(240, 80, font = 'Calibri 18', fill = 'white', text = '     Welcome, Witcher\nPlease Enter Your Name:', )
    
    #creates the name input
    name = StringVar()
    name_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = name, font = 'Calibri 16')
    create_name_entry = c.create_window(238, 136, window = name_entry)

    #button to move on and confirm the name
    confirm_button = Button(c, text = 'Confirm', command = rules_canvas, font = 'Calibri 18')
    create_confirm_button = c.create_window(0, 0, window = confirm_button)

    #button to quit the game
    quit_button = Button(c, text = 'Quit', command = exit_confirmation, font = 'Calibri 18')
    create_quit_button = c.create_window(100, 100, window = quit_button)

def rules_canvas():
    pass

def game_canvas():
    pass

introduction_canvas()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried using a different IDE, on a different file, changing the file format to .gif from .png, nothing works :/

Comment: You should either pass the image as an argument or again make use of the `global` keyword.

Comment: It is caused by creating more than one instance of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` for windows other than the root window.

Answer (score 0):

> "pyimage{number here} not found".

Importing every public name from a module using a wildcard (`from tkinter import *`) is a bad idea because:

- It could lead to conflicts between names defined locally and the ones
  imported.

Don't use valid command `exit`. Use Underscore eg. `_exit`.

- In line 19, replace `exit = Tk()` to `top = tk.Toplevel()`.
- In line 20, prefix `tk.` to `tk.Canvas` inside `exit_confirmation`
  function.
- In line 22, change x and y  coordinate to
  confirmtation_`canvas.create_image(10, 50,...` inside
  `exit_confirmation` function. So we can see image.
- Comment out `exit.mainloop()` inside `exit_confirmation` function.
- In line30, change x and y  coordinate to `c.create_text(280, 80, ...`
  So we can see image.
- In line 41, 45 Use `root` object to replace to `confirm_button = tk.Button(root, ...` inside `introduction_canvas` function. Because you re using outside of function.
- Move all packs such as confirm_button.pack(), quit_button.pack() and
  c.pack() to bottom inside `introduction_canvas` function.
- At then end we must use `if __name__=='__main__':`, will only run if
  that module is the entry point to your program.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

#defining the images
background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='p1.png')
win_screen_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='p2.png')
lose_screen_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='p3.png')
#exit_confirmation_image = tk.PhotoImage(file =r'C:\Temp\banana-dance.gif')

def quit_game():
    root.destroy

#work in progress
def exit_confirmation():
     
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    confirmtation_canvas = tk.Canvas(top, height=202, width=360)
    confirmtation_canvas.pack()
    confirmtation_canvas.create_image(10, 50, image=background_image, anchor='nw')
        
#function to call the intro canvas
def introduction_canvas():
    #creates the canvas
    c = tk.Canvas(root, height=720, width=980)
        
    #places the background image
    c.create_image(0, 20, image=win_screen_image, anchor='nw')
    
    #creates the introduction text
    c.create_text(280, 80, font='Calibri 18', fill='blue', text='Welcome, Witcher"\n"Please Enter Your Name:')
     
    #creates the name input
    name = tk.StringVar()
    name_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=name, font='Calibri 16')
    create_name_entry = c.create_window(238, 136, window=name_entry)

    #button to move on and confirm the name
    confirm_button = tk.Button(root, text='Confirm', command=rules_canvas, font='Calibri 18')
    create_confirm_button = c.create_window(0, 0, window=confirm_button)

    #button to quit the game
    quit_button = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=exit_confirmation, font='Calibri 18')
         
    create_quit_button = c.create_window(100, 100, window=quit_button)
    confirm_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=20, pady=180) 
    quit_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=20, pady=180)
    c.pack()
          
def rules_canvas():
    pass

def game_canvas():
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    introduction_canvas()
    root.mainloop()
```

Snippet:

[image]

Btw, I'm not using `gif`.